# Refreshing the table columns in jsp page on click of refresh button at each row using ajax/javascript

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

Hi I have a JSP page as below,jsp page contains one table in which i am displaying data by iterating through the list from the action class.

each row of a table has refresh button at row level.jsp is as shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function refreshRecord(id)
       {
         $(document).ready(function(){

            var fileId=id;
            alert(fileId);
           $.ajax({
             type:"post",
             url:"checkStatusAndNumRecs",
             data: {fileId:fileId},  
             success:function(data){
             alert("returned from action");
             }
             });
             });    
             }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<%@include file="index1.html" %>
<div class="box2">    
 <div class="box3"> 
<s:property value="userId"/>
</div>  
    <center><h2>FILE STATUS</h2></center>
<center> 

    <form action="Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="myFile" class="text">Upload your file:</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="upload"/>
        <input type="file" name="myFile" size="40"  class="file"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="button"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Refresh" class="button"/>   
    </form>
    </center>        

      <center>
     <table border="1" class="displaytab" id="rtable">
     <s:if test="%{user.roles == 'admin'}">
     <tr>   <td  colspan="10" style="background:#7395B8;color:white;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;"><center>Admin</center></td></tr>
     </s:if>
     <tr> 
     <th>FileId</th><th>File Name</th><th>Upload Date</th><th>#Records</th><th>Status</th><th>Estimated Time</th><th>Processed Records</th><th>Generate Report</th><th></th><s:if test="%{user.roles == 'admin'}"><th>Controls</th></s:if>
     </tr>

     <s:iterator value="uploadList" var="m"> 
        <tr>   
        <td><s:property value="%{#m.fileId}" /></td> 
        <td><s:property value="%{#m.fileName}" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="%{#m.uploadDate}" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="%{#m.numRecords}" /></td>
        <td><s:property value="%{#m.status}" /></td>
        <td>tbd</td>

        <td><s:property value="%{#m.numRecords}" /></td>
        <td><a href=""><img src="images/generate.png" title="Generate Report">    </a></td>
        <td><a href=""><img src="images/refresh.png" title="Refresh" onclick="refreshRecord(<s:property value="%{#m.fileId}" />);"></a></td>
         </tr>
         </s:iterator>
         </table>
         </center>
```

at the refresh button onclick i am calling onclick="refreshRecord();"> this javascript method it will go to action class get the latest values of status and # records.

through ajax i am passing this fileId to action class checkStatusAndNumRecsAction.java to get the updated status and #records column values from database

my action class is as below

```
import com.mxui.db.api.PersistenceService;
import com.mxui.db.service.*;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class checkStatusAndNumRecsAction extends ActionSupport
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6450400234448854648L;

    private String status;

    public String getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) 
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    private long numRecords;

    public long getNumRecords()
    {
        return numRecords;
    }
    public void setNumRecords(long  numRecords) 
    {
        this.numRecords= numRecords;
    }

    private String fileId;
       public String getFileId()
    {
        return fileId;
    }
    public void setFileId(String fileId) 
    {
        this.fileId = fileId;
    }
    public String execute()
    {  
        PersistenceService svc = PersistenceServiceImpl.getInstance();
            status = svc.getStatusByFileId(fileId);
        System.out.println("status is "+status);
        numRecords = svc.getNumRecordsByFileId(fileId);
        System.out.println("num records are "+numRecords);
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

this action get the values of status and #records from database

what i want to do is i should get the values of status and numRecords from action class to jsp using ajax and replace the tables  of status and #records column with the new retrieved data from action class.on click of that row refresh button.

Comment: what problem are you facing? what is not work?

Comment: The data object that you get back on your jquery success callback will contain the response from the servlet.  Inspect this and extract what you need

Comment: problem i am facing is i am not getting ,how to retrieve values of status and #records frm action class and update it in the corresponding columns.

Answer (score 0):

In the function defined in `success:` you will need to write javascript that replaces the contents of the `<TD>` for the record that has been refreshed. You can identify the `<TD>` by using the `fileId`. For example: `<td id="%{#m.fileId}"><s:property value="%{#m.status}" /></td>` and using jQuery search for this fileId and by using replaceWith substitute the new value of status. For example: `$("td#fileId").replaceWith(newStatusData);`

Depending of the format of the data returned to the AJAX call you might need to do some parsing in order to extract the data that you want.

EDIT: Just seen your comment. Can you control to format of the data returned to the AJAX call? If so you might like to format in JSON. Although a simple CSV format would be sufficient. Also can you post an example of the data sent back to the AJAX.

Comment: data will be like this String status = "new" numRecords = 2; these are stroed in variables in action class,these i have to get in my jsp

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing a servlet that recuperates the values from the DB and sends then to the client. In your servlets doPost() method you need to call the methods that return the status of the record and number of records and return them to the client. I imagine servlet code something like this:

```
@WebServlet(checkStatusAndNumRecs)
class MyServlet extends HttpServlet

protected doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse) 
             throws IOException, ServletException{

String fileId = request.getParameter("fileId");
String status = XXXXX.getStatus(fileId);
String numRec = XXXXX.getNumRecords();

String responseTxt = status + "," + numRec;
response.out.println(responseTxt);
response.getWriter().println(responseTxt);

}
```

XXXXX is the object that encapsulates the calls to the DB to retrieve the values of status and record number.

And also you need to change to jQuery AJAX to something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "checkStatusAndNumRecs",
    data: "fileId=" + fileId,
    success: function(data){  
        var rData = data.split(",");
        $("td#fileId").replaceWith(rData[0]);
        // Do the same for the record number data: rData[1]
    }
```